# How to encourage a baby to use rusks or prepare the rusks

Tags: teething

My mother sent us three boxes of rusks  (hard long wheat product- not common product here). How do I encourage him to try putting in his mouth or how do I use the rusks so he will like them? He refuses to let it in and in his hand he throws them away before it gets near his mouth. He is 8 months old with one small tooth.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't rusk supposed to be dry? Just wondering, if the baby is 8 month's and no teeth definitely this will make it difficult for him and rough, maybe you should try to see if he will like the small smooth biscuits for beginners; and maybe try those at 13+ month's when he has some teeth.

Not an expert but I introduced fruits to my boy at 8 month's, I'd cut them in small pieces then let him pick them up and eat. ;) he really enjoyed it, then at 13+ some biscuits.

Comment: It is designed to be sucked or ground. I tried it- it falls apart when the centre gets wet. The packet of the Heinz rusks says from 6 month but doesn't say anything else of note. Any way the question is partly about getting him to try it.